# Python: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple. I looked to other questions and cant find the solution

Tags: python-2.7, typeerror

I looked over and over the code and i cant wrap my head around the problem.
i tried forcing them to make them forced to be integers but then it 
just gives me the the error: "TypeError: int() can't convert non-string with explicit base"
this is my code...

please help stuck with this for a hour...

```
def median(self):
    lenght_list = int(len(self))
    if len(self) % 2 == 0: # check if is even
        key_low = lenght_list / 2
        key_high = key_low + 1
        med_even = (self[key_high] + self[key_low]) / 2
        print med_even
        return med_even
    else: #odd numbers
        key = lenght_list / 2 + 0,5
        med_odd = self[key]
        print med_odd
        return med_odd

median([1,2,3])
median([1,2,3,4])
```

output gives me the following error:

```
C:\Programming\Python27\python.exe "F:/Belangrijke documenten/Oefeningen/Programerren/Python/PyCharm/Learning Python/Test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Belangrijke documenten/Oefeningen/Programerren/Python/PyCharm/Learning Python/Test.py", line 15, in <module>
    median([1,2,3])
  File "F:/Belangrijke documenten/Oefeningen/Programerren/Python/PyCharm/Learning Python/Test.py", line 11, in median
    med_odd = int(self[key])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: please [edit] your question and give the **full text** of the traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is likely the one causing the problem:

```
key = lenght_list / 2 + 0,5
```

When you add the comma `,`, you are creating a tuple with values `(lenght_list / 2, 5)`. I assume you want `0,5` to mean the decimal `0.5`. Replace the comma with a full stop `.` and you should be all set.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaawh fack reallyxD i feel so stupid... thanks for the fast respons btw, always appreciated when people take theire time for you! you sir earned you're self some karma points;) thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
key = lenght_list / 2 + 0,5
```

If you're trying to add one half here, you need to use a period instead of a comma.

```
key = lenght_list / 2 + 0.5
```

Comment: Thanks man for the lightning speed response! That was really nooby from me;) i hope theire will  be a time where in we can download knowledge packets and share a common cloud of all the knowledge of the world. and i can download all the information i need;P till that time i thank you for being a kind being and sharing the information the old way;)